# decoding a PUT request in Netty

Tags: python, netty, http.client

I have created an HTTPServer in Netty with the following handler:

```
public class HttpRouterServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpRequest> {

public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest req) {
  if (HttpUtil.is100ContinueExpected(req)) {
     ctx.writeAndFlush(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.CONTINUE));
     return;
  }

  System.out.println(req.toString());
  HttpResponse res = /* create the response here */      
  flushResponse(ctx, req, res);
}
```

I send the PUT request in Python using http.client:

```
     json_data = /* constructJSON content */
     connection = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost", 8080)
     connection.request("PUT", "/proto/api/send", json_data)     
     response = self.connection.getresponse()
     connection.close()
```

For some reason, I can't get the BODY of the request (the json content). The reason seems to be that my `HttpRequest` is not a `FullHttpRequest`, so I can't get its `content()`

It I print the content of my request, I have something like:

```
DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)
PUT /proto/api/send HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: identity
content-length: 47
```

Also I tried to replace the HttpRequest by FullHttpRequest for my handler, but in this case the Netty server does not respond anymore, which lead to an exception in Python:

```
public class HttpRouterServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {

  public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest req) {
    if (HttpUtil.is100ContinueExpected(req)) {
       ctx.writeAndFlush(new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.CONTINUE));
    return;
  } 

   System.out.println(req.toString());
   HttpResponse res = /* create the response here */      
   flushResponse(ctx, req, res);
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was in the initializer. I did:

```
public class HttpRouterServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
  private final HttpRouterServerHandler handler;

  public HttpRouterServerInitializer(HttpPythonModule module) {
     handler = new HttpRouterServerHandler(moduler);
  }

  public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
     ch.pipeline()
        .addLast(new HttpServerCodec())
        .addLast(handler)
  }
}
```

where I should have done:

```
public class HttpRouterServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
  private final HttpRouterServerHandler handler;

  public HttpRouterServerInitializer(HttpPythonModule module) {
     handler = new HttpRouterServerHandler(moduler);
  }

  public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
     ch.pipeline()
        .addLast(new HttpServerCodec())
        .addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
        .addLast(handler)
  }
}
```

The Netty documentation says about the `HttpObjectAggregator` class:

> A ChannelHandler that aggregates an HttpMessage and its following HttpContents into a single FullHttpRequest or FullHttpResponse (depending on if it used to handle requests or responses) with no following HttpContents.

Comment: For information I did not show this part of the code before because I did not think this was remotely connected to my problem. Turned out it was the reason of my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use `FullHttpRequest`, you will get the following messages:

- One `HttpRequest` message
- Zero or more `HttpContent` messages
- One `LastHttpContent` message

The issue with the first code snippet is that it is only accepting `HttpRequest`, if you want to get all the above messages, you should accept `HttpObject`.

I am not sure what is wrong with the second snippet, most likely you are not receiving the entire content hence `FullHttpRequest` is not created and emitted. I will suggest adding a `LoggingHandler` to the pipeline and see what you receive on the wire.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that ASAP!!

Comment: Thanks again, your remarks helped me to understand my mistake (see the answer below).